# Automatically convert sycl swizzle operation to vector

Tags: c++, sycl

I have the following line of code in a sycl application under a `parallel_for`:

```
  queue.submit(
        [&map, &output](cl::sycl::handler& cgh)
        {
            auto d_image = output.get_access<access::mode::read_write>(cgh);
            auto d_map_probabilities =
                map.probabilities.get_access<access::mode::read>(cgh);
            cgh.parallel_for<class CreateImage>(
                map.probabilities.get_range(),
                [=](id<3> work_position)
                {
                    // ... Code!

                    float3 relative{};
                    float elevation =
                        atan2(relative.z(), length(relative.xy())) * 30.0f * M_2_PI_F;
                }
          }
    );
```

For which i get the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'length'
                        atan2(relative.z(), length(relative.xy())) * 30.0f * M_2_PI_F;
                                            ^~~~~~
/opt/sycl/bin/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/builtins.hpp:1032:7: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'detail::is_contained<sycl::detail::SwizzleOp<sycl::vec<float, 3>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp, 0, 1>, sycl::detail::type_list<sycl::detail::type_list<float>, sycl::detail::type_list<sycl::vec<float, 1>, sycl::vec<float, 2>, sycl::vec<float, 3>, sycl::vec<float, 4>>>>::value' was not satisfied [with T = sycl::detail::SwizzleOp<sycl::vec<float, 3>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp, 0, 1>]
float length(T p) __NOEXC {
      ^
/opt/sycl/bin/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/builtins.hpp:1039:8: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'detail::is_contained<sycl::detail::SwizzleOp<sycl::vec<float, 3>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp, 0, 1>, sycl::detail::type_list<sycl::detail::type_list<double>, sycl::detail::type_list<sycl::vec<double, 1>, sycl::vec<double, 2>, sycl::vec<double, 3>, sycl::vec<double, 4>>>>::value' was not satisfied [with T = sycl::detail::SwizzleOp<sycl::vec<float, 3>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp, 0, 1>]
double length(T p) __NOEXC {
       ^
/opt/sycl/bin/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/builtins.hpp:1046:6: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'detail::is_contained<sycl::detail::SwizzleOp<sycl::vec<float, 3>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp, 0, 1>, sycl::detail::type_list<sycl::detail::type_list<sycl::detail::half_impl::half>, sycl::detail::type_list<sycl::vec<sycl::detail::half_impl::half, 1>, sycl::vec<sycl::detail::half_impl::half, 2>, sycl::vec<sycl::detail::half_impl::half, 3>, sycl::vec<sycl::detail::half_impl::half, 4>>>>::value' was not satisfied [with T = sycl::detail::SwizzleOp<sycl::vec<float, 3>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp, 0, 1>]
half length(T p) __NOEXC {
     ^
```

Basically it comes down to this. The operation `relative.xy()` produces the type:

```
sycl::detail::SwizzleOp<sycl::vec<float, 3>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp<float>, sycl::detail::GetOp, 0, 1>
```

which is not implicitly convertible to `float2` which is required by the length function. It should be though, this was fine to do in opencl. This can be solved by the workaround:

```
float2 rel_part = relative.xy();
float elevation = atan2(relative.z(), length(rel_part)) * 30.0f * M_2_PI_F;
```

Or

```
float elevation = atan2(relative.z(), length(float2{relative.xy()})) * 30.0f * M_2_PI_F;
```

But this defeats the purpose of a nice swizzle definition. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I think this is a DPC++ CTAD bug. This works: `length<float2>(relative.xy())`. I can raise this on the DPC++ issue tracker with relevant implementation details, if you like?

Comment: https://github.com/intel/llvm/issues/6402

Comment: According to section [4.14.2.1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/SYCL/specs/sycl-2020/html/sycl-2020.html#_vec_interface) from SYCL 2020 spec, `XYZW_SWIZZLE()` returns a value of `__swizzled_vec__` type. And according to 4.17.1 and  4.17.8 sections, `length()` doesn't have overload for this type. So, according to the specification, it necessary to materialize swizzle to `vec_t` first. It possible to use already mentioned variants or `length(relative.xy().as<float2>())` or even `length(+relative.xy())`. But I fully agree, that it is more convenient to use `length(relative.xy())` in the code.

Comment: @JoeTodd Nice. That was quick.